# Is it possible to narrow down to and only include specific words in search-function, Google maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, keyword-search, wordsearch

I´m going to build an interactive frontend webpage with a simple map-function. I will include 10 cities from a sustainable cities-list, to choose from in the search field. Now my question is, after you have chosen one of these cities from this search field - if it´s possible to build a list to choose from, with specific words to look for in the chosen city, for example instead of choosing "restaurants" or "accommodations", have words like "organic" or "eco". My hope is that this word search will find all the places in the city with the e.g word "organic" in it, like "The organic market" or "Organic food-store" and so on. Is there a function where I can narrow down the search for these specific words in a list of like 15 by me pre-chosen words, and that this will not include all the possible imaginable words in the world, in this search field? - but instead exclude all the other words than my pre-chosen ones like "organic" or "eco" etc? 
-Also, is the Google maps API best for this, or Google-places API?

Answer (score 0):

Using Places API's [Text Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests), you can search for keywords/text string and the API will return a list of places matching the text string and any location bias that you will set.

For client-side implementation, please refer to this guide: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests

Hope this helps!